# How to know if a child route has been rendered (from the parent component)

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have defined two routes, one of them being child of the other one:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'invoices', component: InvoicesComponent, children: [
      {
        path: 'new-invoice', component: NewInvoiceComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

So my app has two paths: `/invoices` and `/invoices/new-invoice`. Also, the component InvoicesComponent has a router-outlet in its template in order to render the child component:

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let invoice of invoices">
        // ...
    </li>
</ul>
```

My question is: how can I know, from the parent Component, whether the router is rendering the child path/component or not. I'd like to know how to ask for an specific child path/component, not just if the router is rendering any child route.

Comment: Hi! Can you be more specific on what to achieve? What you can use to actually see if the route is successful or not is by looking for the route event [NavigationEnd](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationEnd) in router events

Comment: Hi @Lucho. I just want to know if the parent component is able to know when the router has rendered the child component (sorry, I don't know how to be more specific). My parent component must set a boolean property depending on that. I've tried to subscribe to router events, but it doesn't emit events if I write the URL by hand in the browser, only works if I navigate inside the app.

Comment: Well you just explained details in the end there that sort of potentially explains your issue. Is your angular app an Angular Universal app (SSR app) or a SPA (meaning a full client-side app)?

Comment: My app is a SPA.